# How can I add a TAB to every line into the very last column only?

Tags: awk, sed, tabs

How can I add a TAB to every line into the very last column only, and keep the rest untouched?

before:

```
hgege  uezeze  uge   847.884  uehe   76,34 84,89
jewhwehew\theghe..846,65 93,48
jerhewgpwi   wquzqwgfedcf\tjwegew...75,93   83
```

after:

```
hgege  uezeze  uge   847.884  uehe   76,34\t84,89
jewhwehew\theghe..846,65\t93,48
jerhewgpwi   wquzqwgfedcf\tjwegew...75,93\t83
```

Comment: 846,65 (is like 846.65) then there is a space  and the next number is 93,48(like 93.48)  sorry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this using awk:

```
awk '{s=$NF;--NF;printf "%s\t%s\n",$0,s}' file
```

Save the last field into the variable `s`. Decrement `NF` so the last field is cut from `$0`. Print `$0`, followed by a tab character, followed by the last field.

Using GNU sed, here's an alternative that preserves the previous tabs in the line:

```
sed -r 's/(.*)[[:space:]]+(.*)/\1\t\2/' file
```

It greedily matches everything up to the last spaces on the line, capturing the content before and after. The replacement is the first part, followed by a tab character, followed by the last part.

Comment: @Ed I'm _guessing_ that the `\t` in the input represent tab characters and the `...` on the last line indicates that it has been shortened. Who knows, maybe there's a space before the 83, in which case this would work! Obviously, it's up to the OP to clarify. Thanks for the info about decrementing `NF`.